# Как удаленно переустановить сервер?

Tags: unix, ssh, linux

Есть удаленный Debian-сервер, который в силу разных причин частично неработоспособен. К нему можно подключиться по ssh под рутом. Есть ли возможность этот сервер переустановить, войдя как администратор по ssh? Если есть, то как это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно посмотреть в сторону [Debootstrap](http://wiki.debian.org/Debootstrap):

> Debootstrap - это инструмент, который установит базовую систему Debian в каталог с другой, уже установленной системой. Он не требует установочный CD, только доступ к репозиторию Debian. Он также может устанавливаться и работать с другой операционной системой, поэтому, например, можно использовать Debootstrap, чтобы установить Debian на неиспользуемый раздел с работающей системы Gentoo.

Алгоритм примерно такой:

1. создать новое устройство на свободном месте диска,
2. установиться на это устройство с помощью debootstrap,
3. перезагрузиться на свежую установку.

[Установка Debian GNU/Linux из системы Unix/Linux](http://www.debian.org/releases/stable/mips/apds03.html.ru).

Answer (score 0):

Если вы хотите полностью переустановить ОС, то это по ssh невозможно.С KVM-over-ip можно такое провернуть, но это совсем другая песня и затраты. ))